# How can I obtain amino acid sequence from this URL?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to obtain amino acid sequence from below url by using python and Selenium, but couldn't succeed. http://flybase.org/download/sequence/FBgn0003719/FBpp

I've tried u Beautiful Soup and Selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('http://flybase.org/download/sequence/FBgn0003719/FBpp')

iframe = driver.find_element_by_class_name('scroller')

notification_element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('fastaSeq')

print(notification_element)
```

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

Answer (score 0):

You can use `selenium` to load the page and `BeautifulSoup` to access the sequence:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
d.get('http://flybase.org/download/sequence/FBgn0003719/FBpp')
sequence = soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser').find('div', {'class':'fastaSeq'}).text
```

Output:

```
'MKGMRLMPMK MKAKLVVLSV GALWMMMFFL VDYAEGRRLS QLPESECDFD FKEQPEDFFG ILDSSLVPPK EPKDDIYQLK TTRQHSGRRR KQSHKSQNKA ALRLPPPFLW TDDAVDVLQH SHSPTLNGQP IQRRRRAVTV RKERTWDYGV IPYEIDTIFS GAHKALFKQA MRHWENFTCI KFVERDPNLH ANYIYFTVKN CGCCSFLGKN GNGRQPISIG RNCEKFGIII HELGHTIGFH HEHARGDRDK HIVINKGNIM RGQEYNFDVL SPEEVDLPLL PYDLNSIMHY AKNSFSKSPY LDTITPIGIP PGTHLELGQR KRLSRGDIVQ ANLLYKCASC GRTYQQNSGH IVSPHFIYSG NGVLSEFEGS GDAGEDPSAE SEFDASLTNC EWRITATNGE KVILHLQQLH LMSSDDCTQD YLEIRDGYWH KSPLVRRICG NVSGEVITTQ TSRMLLNYVN RNAAKGYRGF KARFEVVCGG DLKLTKDQSI DSPNYPMDYM PDKECVWRIT APDNHQVALK FQSFELEKHD GCAYDFVEIR DGNHSDSRLI GRFCGDKLPP NIKTRSNQMY IRFVSDSSVQ KLGFSAALML DVDECKFTDH GCQHLCINTL GSYQCGCRAG YELQANGKTC EDACGGVVDA TKSNGSLYSP SYPDVYPNSK QCVWEVVAPP NHAVFLNFSH FDLEGTRFHY TKCNYDYLII YSKMRDNRLK KIGIYCGHEL PPVVNSEQSI LRLEFYSDRT VQRSGFVAKF VIDVDECSMN NGGCQHRCRN TFGSYQCSCR NGYTLAENGH NCTETRCKFE ITTSYGVLQS PNYPEDYPRN IYCYWHFQTV LGHRIQLTFH DFEVESHQEC IYDYVAIYDG RSENSSTLGI YCGGREPYAV IASTNEMFMV LATDAGLQRK GFKATFVSEC GGYLRATNHS QTFYSHPRYG SRPYKRNMYC DWRIQADPES SVKIRFLHFE IEYSERCDYD YLEITEEGYS MNTIHGRFCG KHKPPIIISN SDTLLLRFQT DESNSLRGFA ISFMAVDPPE DSVGEDFDAV TPFPGYLKSM YSSETGSDHL LPPSRLI'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the dedicated API found in the network tab then only `requests` is required.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://flybase.org/api/sequence/id/FBgn0003719/FBpp').json()
print(r['resultset']['result'][0]['sequence'])
```